# Google API tutorials

Tags: web-apis

I want to create a program like when we give the country name it should display the provinces inside that country and the same thing has to happen until getting the house address. (e.g. if I give one country's district name it has to give the villages name under that district).For that, I need to know which google API can help me to do so and I also want to know is there any tutorials available for this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about google but OpenStreetMap has boundary relations which contains the inner divisions as members. e.g. https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/4583216

Comment: OpenStreetMap has matured a lot and could be a really great resource for what you want to do.